# Angular JS Service error inside web service

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use Angular JS service for various purpose. I already made functions inside main script.js but want to shift in employeeService.js service file. Inside it, I am trying to implement a Delete functionality,Here is code-

```
/// <reference path="script.js" />
app.factory('fetchEmpService', function () {
    var deleteEmp = function (EID) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")) {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'EmpWebService.asmx/DeleteEmployee',
                data: { EmpId: EID },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
            })
        .then(function (reponse) {
            alert("Deleted successfully.");
            $scope.getEmployee();
        });
        }
    }
    return {
        deleteEmp:deleteEmp,
    };
});
```

And in my main script.js file-

```
 $http.get("EmpWebService.asmx/GetEmp")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response.data;
        });
```

The sevice is running and control goes inside it but its throwing following error-
angular.js:5582 ReferenceError: $http is not defined.

Similarly I was trying to call a method of fetching EmployeeList function its giving error. What may be the reason?
Is there any issue regarding web service that I am using?

Comment: $scope is not injectable in factory or service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `$http` into your factory. You then want to return the promise and update the `$scope` inside a closure inside your controller

```
app.factory('fetchEmpService', function ($http) {
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks,that was the reason.

Comment: also `$scope.getEmployee()` function would not work inside factory, as `$scope` can not be get injected in factory

Comment: Can we inject $scope also in function